# Clear Cache in IE10 through code in angularJs Application

Tags: angularjs, caching, browser-cache

I've developed an AngularJS SPA application, I'm seeing issues with my js files being mixed with the older versions because of cache even after the new deployment. Anyone know how to clear the cache through the angular code or some js code or through html every time the app loads for the first time, so that it won't mix both the new and old code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is typically done by having version numbers in the tags:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/jsfile.js?v=1'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/cssfile.css?v=1">
```

Then you just increment the versions every time you want to force an update.

Comment: thanks Nguyen. what If I'm using asp.net mvcs bundleConfig.cs to load all the files from a directory like below and how will the compiler know the version is there anything that we need to do in .js file to indicate the version, bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/application").Include(
                        "~/application/application.js",
                        "~/application/routes.js",                        
                        "~/application/controllers/*.js",
                        "~/application/directives/*.js",
                        "~/application/services/*.js"));

Comment: I'm not familiar with asp.net but I'm assuming there is a way of storing the version in a config. So assuming that asp is compiling all of the js files into 'app.js' you can probably do something like 'app.js?v={version_num}' where version_num is a variable somewhere.

Sorry I can't be more help on asp.net.

Comment: Its okay thanks for your attempt to help me though. I appreciate it.